# How to find a specific characters in string without spaces in python?

Tags: python, string

Hey I have loop for reading files and processing them. I want exclude some files from this loop.

Let's say file names are:
(they are all in the same directory called "data")

```
'123abc456.csv'
'123bca456.csv'
'455abc324.csv'
```

and I want to exclude files which in name contains 'bca' part. I don't want to read them.

How I can do it?

```
for file in glob.glob("path/data/*csv"):
   if "bca" in file: 
      None 
   else:
     df = df.read_csv(file)
```

is not working. I'm receiving also "bca" files.

Thanks!

Comment: `glob.glob` returns full paths, does `bca` exist in the directory names ?

Comment: Your code works as expected, no file containing 'bca' gets printed. Check your output or your version of the code.

Comment: Only in file name like this: "/data/test/files/123bca456.csv"

Comment: What about the "without spaces" bit in the title? I don't see spaces in either the file name or the pattern. Or are there some files that have e.g. `"b ca"` and you want to exclude those, too?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to make your expectations clearer, and provide simple, well chosen examples of filenames you want to accept/reject.

Comment: I meant that is string like 'fpiajorange238' and we have to find word orange, when it would be 'aw9 orange 23998' would be different approach I think

Comment: BTW, the idiomatic way for that `if/else` would be to use `pass`, not `None`. Or better, use `not in` (or `not (...)` for more general conditions) and drop the `else` entirely.

Comment: @Aly I still don't understand what you mean. Please edit your question with simple examples of accepted/rejected filenames, and the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [183]: filenames
Out[183]: ['123abc456.csv', '123bca456.csv', '455abc324.csb']

In [184]: [x for x in filenames if 'bca' not in x]
Out[184]: ['123abc456.csv', '455abc324.csb']
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you describe what your code is doing and/or how it helps them.

Answer (score 0):

You can negate the expression using not like this:

Assuming your path is "/home/user/Documents/*"

```
import glob

for file_path in glob.glob("/home/user/Documents/*"):
    if not "bca" in file:
        print(file_path)
        # do something with file
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try

```
for file in glob.glob("path/data/*csv"):
if "bca" not in file: 
  df = df.read_csv(file)
```